# Cannot select item from Drop down selenium WITHOUT select

Tags: selenium

I am new to Python and trying to figure out how to call an item from the drop down list. I managed to make it visible with this code.
price_point = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("chosen-single")
price_point[0].click()
I cannot use Select. 
The list is open and visible now But I am not able to click the items inside the list. Any ideas? 
Your help is much appreciate!

Comment: Use the `Select` class from `selenium.webdriver.support.ui`. More info here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select

Comment: The teacher does not want use using select class

Answer (score 0):

Access the list item directly and click on it. Here is the sample

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='chosen-single']//option[normalize-space(.)='here goes your list item text']").click()
```

if you have more than one list boxes with class "chosen-single" then use the below to select the item from first list box.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select[@class='chosen-single'])[1]//option[normalize-space(.)='here goes your list item text']").click()
```

Comment: What is **`normalize-space(,)`** ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected it to `noramlize-space(.)`